# Link area bigger than the image

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem in my website. I have buttons in my menu. These buttons are two images but the link area is bigger than them.

```css
.header-options .element-button {
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.element-button {
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0.2em 10px .3em 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff!important;
    background:#4e8ed6;
}
.element-button.primary,
.element-button.active {
    color:#fff!important;
    border-color:#ea6254;
    background:#ea6254;
}

.element-button.opaque {
    border-color:#fff;
    /*background-color:#1c4464;*/
    background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-options right clearfix">
<a href="#" class="element-button opaque"><img src="button_1.png" width="80%" height="35" style="display:inline-block!important"></a>
<a href="#link" class="element-button primary" style="background:transparent"><img src="button_2.png" width="80%" height="35" style="display:inline-block!important"></a>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the `anchor` tag will be bigger than the `image`. This is because you have applied the `width` of image as `80%`. This will result in filling the image only to `80%` of the parent, which is the `anchor` tag. Apply width and height to the `anchor` tag and let the `image` consumes full width of the parent. Here is a working example.

```css
.header-options .element-button {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;

  /* Added */
  width: 80%;
  height: 35px;
}

/* Added */
.header-options .element-button img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.element-button {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 10px 0.3em 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #4e8ed6;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.element-button.primary,
.element-button.active {
  color: #fff !important;
  border-color: #ea6254;
  background: #ea6254;
}

.element-button.opaque {
  border-color: #fff;
  /*background-color:#1c4464;*/
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-options right clearfix">
  <a href="#" class="element-button opaque"
    >
    <!-- Changed -->
    <img
      src="https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20171217/2d3/button-png-5a3740be62b8c9.0157484515135704944044.jpg"
      style="display:inline-block!important"
  /></a>
  <a
    href="#link"
    class="element-button primary"
    style="background:transparent"
    ><img
      src="https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20171217/2d3/button-png-5a3740be62b8c9.0157484515135704944044.jpg"
      style="display:inline-block!important"
  /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: you are welcome. please approve my answer. happy to have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your padding for the `.element-button` class. Try removing it from your CSS code or replacing it with `padding: 0`.

```css
.element-button {
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff!important;
    background:#4e8ed6;
}
```

Edit: Also the `img` tags have an `80%` width where as the `a` tags have `100%`. Try moving the `80%` width from the `img` tag to the `a` tag.

```html
<div class="header-options right clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="element-button opaque" width="80%"><img src="button_1.png" height="35" style="display:inline-block!important"></a>
    <a href="#link" class="element-button primary" style="background:transparent" width="80%"><img src="button_2.png" height="35" style="display:inline-block!important"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The link area is a little smaller now but still bigger than the images.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps there is something else here. Do you have any other CSS code that affects these elements/classes?

Comment: Oh, the img has a width of 80%, try moving this to the `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

I use this way in these cases:

```css
a{
display: block;
}

img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
object-position: center;
}
```